# Why doesn't drupal_render work, but render does?

Tags: 7, theming

I've a piece of code what is rendering a custom table (see var_dump below) what is shown on for specific states of the node. The data of the table is for both states the same.

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["#theme"]=>
    string(5) "table"
    ["#header"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "test"
      [1]=>
      string(9) "geen test"
    }
    ["#rows"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        [1]=>
        string(6) "e1a1r1"
        [2]=>
        string(6) "e1a2r1"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        [1]=>
        string(6) "e1a1r2"
        [2]=>
        string(6) "e1a2r2"
      }
    }
    ["#prefix"]=>
    string(38) "<h3>Table</h3>"
    ["#attributes"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["class"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(15) "previous-scheme"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The custom states of the node are determined by a condition what prints one of the following gathered variables.

For the variable at the line below works with both drupal_render and render.

```
$kickoff_deadline .= '<h2>Between kickoff and deadline</h2>'.drupal_render($table);
```

For the variable at the line below only works with render, without it wont show anything.

```
$after_deadline .= '<h2>After the deadline</h2>'.render($table);
```

So what is happening? Why doesn't drupal_render work for a similar printed variable what does work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you've done this:

```
$kickoff_deadline .= '<h2>Between kickoff and deadline</h2>'.drupal_render($table);
```

The render array is marked as `#printed`, and won't be rendered again. So this

```
$after_deadline .= '<h2>After the deadline</h2>' . drupal_render($table);
```

Will do nothing.

If you take a look at the code for [`render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/render/7):

```
function render(&$element) {
  if (is_array($element)) {
    show($element);
    return drupal_render($element);
  }
  else {
    // Safe-guard for inappropriate use of render() on flat variables: return
    // the variable as-is.
    return $element;
  }
}
```

You can see it runs `show($element);`, making it available for rendering again. Which is why this works:

```
$after_deadline .= '<h2>After the deadline</h2>'.render($table);
```

Comment: So performance related it would be the best solution to use one of the two function, right? This is how that can be done with drupal_render. By storing the render action into a variable `$rendered_table=drupal_render($table);` and than.. `$kickoff_deadline='...'.$rendered_table; `$after_deadline='...'.$rendered_table;`

Comment: Correct @Fleuv - you'll save processing time and a bit of memory by caching the result in a local var

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the documentation for those functions there are hints to this.

[drupal_render()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render/7) will only render the element if it has not already been printed and has not been hidden using [hide()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/hide/7).

[render()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/render/7) on the other hand will always render the element because it calls [show()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/show/7) on the element before then calling drupal_render() on it.